# DreamFactory 2.0.4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, swagger, user-roles

When I send a request to my new DSP I get a 404

```
GET http://example.com/api/v2/sericename/_table/tablename 404 (Not Found)
```

In the Apache error.log I see

```
... Got error: PHP message: REST Exception #404 > Role not found ...
```

The role and user are configured properly and almost the same way as in DSP 1.9.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving from DreamFactory 1.x to 2.0, the header X-DreamFactory-Application-Name was deprecated. Moving forward the correct header is X-DreamFactory-API-Key. Using the older header will result in this error.